# Open a file from a specific program from python

Tags: python, macos, blender

I would like to do a very simple thing but I am quite lost.

I am using a program called Blender and I want to write a script in python which open a .blend file but using the blender.app which is located in the same folder with the blend file, not with the blender.app which is located in Applications. (using Macosx)

So I was thinking that this should do the job...but instead it opens blender twice...

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
os.system("cd path/")
os.system("open blender.app Import_mhx.blend")
```

I also tried this one

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
os.system("cd path/")
os.system("open Import_mhx.blend")
```

but unfortunately it opens the .blend file with the default blender.app which is located in Applications...

any idea?

Comment: you're actually cd'ing into a folder called `path` inside the current directory, is this a typo?

Comment: @agf Well, I tried with this one, but still it opens two blenders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot work since the `system` command gets executed in a subshell, and the `chdir` is only valid for that subshell. Replace the command by

```
os.system("open -a path/blender.app Import_mhx.blend")
```

or (much better)

```
subprocess.check_call(["open", "-a", os.path.join(path, "blender.app"),
                       "Import_mhx.blend"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried telling the `open` command to open it WITH a specific application?

`open -a /path/to/blender.app /path/to/Import_mhx.blend`

Your first attempt was on the right track but you were really telling `open` to just open two different things. Not one with the other.

Comment: Well, the one that you suggested it didn't work...You are right. It opens two different things but both of them empty!

Comment: it still opens two different blenders

Comment: That makes no sense. Then why would @Philipp's answer be any different? It has nothing to do with os.system vs subprocess. I feel like you forgot to add the -a flag

Comment: I am confirming though that your issue was not including the -a flag in your attempt. My answer suggested using -a and it make your file open with that given application path. It works just the same as @Phillips answer, yet he added the subprocess which is the same thing really.

Comment: Well I tried it, using the first solution of philip and yours and it doesn't work actually. Am I missing smth here?

Comment: You must be, because it works absolutely fine. Maybe something wrong with your paths in your command. I used absolute paths.

Comment: maybe it's because of the paths.